# Mercurial: Converting existing folders into sub-repos

Tags: mercurial-subrepos

I have a Mercurial repository that looks like this:

```
SWClients/
  SWCommon
  SWB
  SWNS
```

...where SWCommon is a a library common to the other two projects. Now, I want to convert SWCommon into a sub-repository of SWClients, so I followed the instructions [here](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/) and [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository?action=show&redirect=subrepos). However, in contrast to the example in the first link I want my sub-repository to have the same name as the folder had at the beginning. In detail, this is what I have done:

Create a file map.txt as follows

```
include SWCommon
rename SWCommon .
```

Create a file .hgsub as follows

```
SWCommon = SWCommon
```

Then run

```
$ hg --config extensions.hgext.convert= convert --filemap map.txt . SWCommon-temp
...lots of stuff happens...
```

Then

```
$ cd SWCommon-temp
$ hg update
101 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ cd ..
$ mv SWCommon SWCommon-old
$ mv SWCommon-temp SWCommon
$ hg status
abort: path 'SWCommon/SWCommon.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/malte.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/SWCommon.xcscheme' is inside nested repo 'SWCommon'
```

...which is indeed the case, but why is that a reason to abort? The other strange thing is that if I do not do that last 'mv' above and I execute an 'hg status' then, I end up with lots of 'missing' files in SWCommon as you would expect. The example in the link never makes it this far and basically stops on the hg update above? How do you make it work in practice?

Answer (score 3):

Not currently possible. You could create a new repo converting the original one like:

```
$ hg --filemap excludemap.txt SWClients SWClients-without-SWCommon
```

With a excludemap.txt like:

```
exclude "SWCommon"
```

And then add the subrepo there.

```
$ hg --filemap map.txt SWCommon SWClients-without-SWCommon/SWCommon
$ cd SWClients-without-SWCommon
$ hg add SWCommon
$ hg ci -m "Created subrepo"
```

See the [mailing list thread](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2011-May/038432.html) that discusses this problem.